# How to rename a file in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I wonder if there is a way that allows me to rename an opened file in Sublime Text 3?

Renaming would include that the currently opened file is created under a different name and deleted under the old name.

Comment: This should not have been closed. Yes, it asked for a plugin, but there is an answer on how to do this natively. A two word edit makes this question in scope for SO, as it is about a tool used for programming.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is a package for Sublime Text 3 I wrote:

https://github.com/brianlow/FileRename

Comment: Maybe this was the valid answer in 2014. It is built into sublime text 3 : Shift+Ctrl+P -> Rename File , see answer from starscream_disco_party

Answer (score 57):

There's way too many people suggesting plugins for something simple and built into Sublime's [Package Manager](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

In Sublime 3 there is a built in command within Package Manager. So:
`Shift+(Ctrl|Cmd)+p -> Rename File`

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: This *is* the answer.

Answer (score 14):

There's the **SideBarEnhancements** plugin that does this.

You can find it on GitHub here: https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements/tree/st3

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. On the Github page of the extension, the following information can be found: `It should be mentioned that the package's context menu is only available for files and folders in a project (section Folders in the side bar), and not on the open files listed at the top of the side bar, due to a limitation of ST.` Does anyone know more about that limitation? Because this is exactly what I was looking for. To rename an opened file which is not part of a project.

Comment: After installing SideBarEnhancements, create the key map with the line `{ "keys": ["Your Shortcut Here"], "command": "side_bar_move" }`

Comment: This is better solution

Answer (score 4):

I recently added the functionality to [AdvancedNewFile](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile). It should rename the currently opened view, assuming you have the appropriate permissions at the source and destination locations. If you try it and run into an issue though, please create an issue on the github page.

Comment: That looks promising. Thanks! I added `{
 "show_sidebar_menu": true
}` to `AdvancedNewFile.sublime-settings` but I still cannot see any option in the sidebar to rename a file when clicking on it in the sidebar. Do I miss something else?

Comment: Ah right now, I only have the side bar sets up to create a new file. Can you create an issue for me so I don't forget. I'll try to get to that in the next few days. I'll also update the issue when it's done, so you'll know right away (if you have email notification on I suppose).

Comment: Thanks! See this issue: https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile/issues/57

Comment: AdvancedNewFile now supports renaming a file in the buffer view. Great!

Comment: **Warning:** as of 2014.12.21, ANF rename moves the file to the "current project directory" by default. The currently accepted alternative ([FileRename](https://github.com/brianlow/FileRename)) doesn't have this problem. I've created [an issue to track this](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile/issues/119). Hope it gets fixed, as ANF seems to have nice features apart from that: e.g. it can automatically do `git mv` apparently, and provides a *"Delete Current File"* command too.

Comment: @akavel I've pushed a fix in v1.5.1 of AdvancedNewFile.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install AdvanceNewFile package from package manager.
   Link: https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile
2. Use ctr+shift+p to open command window of sublime.
3. Enter Rename and select ANF: Rename File

Advantage of this package is you can also move and delete the file with rename.